# Android LinearLayout horizontally or vertically oriented items fill remaining space

Tags: android, android-layout

I wonder if it is possible to have two items in a LinearLayout one wraps its content and the other fills the remaining horizontal space. I do this frequently in WPF (.NET) by specifying

```
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch".
```

For example:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:background="#0000FF"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:background="#FF0000"/>
```

When I do this the second `ImageView` fill the whole horizontal space as I expected. I tried to set both wrap_content and use gravity such as `android:gravity="start"` and `android:gravity="fill_horizontal"` for the second one it did not worked.

NOTE: I can achieve something similar by specifying weight attribute. But this is providing a division according to the percent value. This is not I want.

Comment: Demir, atleast in one ImageView you have to give space, or another solution is you need to declare both ImageViews in Seperate LinearLayout.

Comment: Use Relative layout instead of linear layout

Comment: you mean fills the remaining horizontal and vertical space? can you add an image what it should look like

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using the weight attribute itself. Try the following method

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:background="#0000FF"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FF0000"/>
```

include this in your horizontal linear layout

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Relative layout for this. Also you either need to specify a width for first image view or it should contain an image otherwise, how can the imageview wrap the content.

You can use like below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:id="@+id/imgFirst"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:background="#0000FF" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="@+id/imgFirst"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgFirst"
    android:background="#FF0000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```